# How to reduce spacing between Items in data table and make texts align end using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a screen as the below image:

[image: Real Image]

and this is the below code I created:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:catest/config/app_theme.dart';
import '../widgets/radio_btn_sim.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 100,
                    left: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Sim information',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      DataTable(
                        columns: [
                          DataColumn(label: Text('Sim operator')),
                          DataColumn(
                              label: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Vodafone'),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/vodic.png',
                                width: 30,
                                height: 30,
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                        ],
                        rows: [
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/sim_ic.png',
                                  width: 30,
                                  height: 30,
                                ),
                                Text('ICCID'),
                              ],
                            )),
                            DataCell(Text('123456789')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('IMEI')),
                            DataCell(Text('123456789')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('SIM IMSI')),
                            DataCell(Text('123456789')),
                          ]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                //Network provider
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20,
                    left: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Network Provider',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      DataTable(
                        columns: [
                          DataColumn(label: Text('Operator')),
                          DataColumn(
                              label: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Vodafone NL'),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/vodic.png',
                                width: 30,
                                height: 30,
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                        ],
                        rows: [
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('MCC'),
                              ],
                            )),
                            DataCell(Text('204')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('MNC')),
                            DataCell(Text('04')),
                          ]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                //Serving Cell
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20,
                    left: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Serving Cell',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      DataTable(
                        columns: [
                          DataColumn(label: Text('Data Net')),
                          DataColumn(
                              label: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('LTE'),
                            ],
                          )),
                        ],
                        rows: [
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Data type'),
                              ],
                            )),
                            DataCell(Text('LTE')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('TAC')),
                            DataCell(Text('62603')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('PCI')),
                            DataCell(Text('118')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('ECI')),
                            DataCell(Text('12315644(5465-567)')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('EARFCN')),
                            DataCell(Text('1300/19300')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('EARFCN')),
                            DataCell(Text('1300/19300')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('FREQ')),
                            DataCell(Text('1815/1720')),
                          ]),
                          DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text('BAND')),
                            DataCell(Text('3 FDD')),
                          ]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: RadioBtnSim(
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the final output looks like the below image:

[image: Result]

So now it's nearly looks like the design I created, but I need here to reduce spacing between rows and the right data should be align right....

I tried to use `Align` widget by wrapping the child and use the `Alignment.centerRight` but it doesn't work..

So is it able to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you need column and row because there is not any property of DataTable that align text right.Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata how can I use this, and how about for reducing the spacing between rows :)

Comment: you can give the space between row and specify the mainAxisAlignment.

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata thanks for your comment, but how can I do that could you give me some example :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in data table you can use `dataRowHeight: double,` to change the height.

from document in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable/dataRowHeight.html

> The height of each
> row (excluding the row that contains column headings).
>
> This value defaults to kMinInteractiveDimension to adhere to the
> Material Design specifications.

and for control column space you can use `columnSpacing`

document of DataTable widget:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the combination of Row and Column like this

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text("Name : "),
        Text(decodedToken['name'].toString()),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text("Email : "),
        Text(decodedToken['email'].toString()),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: thank you I got you now, really that's was my first technique but I change it by using `DataTable` instead :(

Comment: yes, most of the people are doing same but there are many limitations of the DataTable widget.

Comment: even we can not make Data Table with different Row size using DataTable and also not theme as well which we can set to table